# Convert given range values to domain values in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a linear scale:

```
var xRange.range([0, parentWidth]).domain([0, 100]);
```

Now on mouseover I get xy coords of the mouse cursor using `d3.mouse(container)`. Then I show a floating tooltip. I need to put xy values calculated from mouse position according to the xRange scale.

How do I do it? Or do I have to create another scale with swapped range and domain values?

Comment: Are you looking for https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_invert ?

Comment: Exactly, how could I miss it? If you put it as an answer, I will mark it, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need for another scale. For linear (numeric) input you can use [`linear.invert()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_invert), which:

> Returns the value in the input domain x for the corresponding value in the output range y. This represents the inverse mapping from range to domain.

**Example:**

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,50])
        .range([0,100]);

// domain to range:
x(25); // 50

// range to domain:
x.invert(50); // 25
```

Comment: More good news: invert() exists for other scales, too, e.g. log, pow and date.

Comment: FYI - this function does not exist for band or ordinal scales.

Comment: What if the domain is for example [-50,50]? In that case I obtain 0 instead a negative domain value.

Comment: @Oleg Sorry, I've asked the question very poorly. In the case of pseudo histogram, that is histogram with "negative" and "positive" bars, the max between 0 and the negative domain value would be used on linear scale to plot the negative rect, so the invert would return 0 and not the original negative domain value.